# position div at the bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

I have a div nested inside another

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

THE CSS is as

```
#wrapper{
width:800px;
}
 #left{
 float:left;
 width: 200px;
 }
#right{
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
#footer{
  width:800px;
  height: 20px; 
}
```

How can i ensure that the footer stays at the bottom of the wrapper div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LMeZ9/

just use clear:both

```
#footer{
  width:800px;
  height: 20px;
  clear:both
}
```

Comment: I use clear both because some times people float one item left and the other right.  but there is also clear:left; and clear:right;

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using positioning:

```
#wrapper{
width:800px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
 #left{
 float:left;
 width: 200px;
 }
#right{
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
#footer{
  width:800px;
  height: 20px; 
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FKU6L/).